# Path not available for process httpd

Tags: linux, bash, apache, path

I'm stuck with the following issue.

I have a command on a specific directory "MyCommand". 
This specific command is on my path

```
set 
PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/cadnat/com/script:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/cadnat/sec/bin
```

The path is on my ~/.bash_profile and is too in my /etc/profile

I can call my command on the current bash. No problem !

I can  call my command on the bash of apache

```
su -s /bin/bash apache
MyCommand --> OK
```

I've got some web site that call this command (it a specific command that implement security connection to the web app ! Whatever, problem is not here. Nothing changed here. It worked for 2 years but doesn't work anymore since sunday (reboot of the server, nothing more). i'm on a CentOS.

So httpd make a call to the command Mycommand

On my logs , i see :

```
tail -f /var/log/http/error_log
sh: MyCommand: command not found
```

Do you know chere to find the solution ?

Comment: Error from sh! Not Bash. You must change sh to bash.